# Prove that if the constraints to a linear program are integer, then the optimal solution is rational

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I've got the following question that I can't quite figure out.

[image]

I have a vague idea of how to do this.

**Attempt**

Assume, for contradiction, that the optimal solution $x*$ is not rational. This means that for at least one of the variables $x_i*$, $x_i*$ can't be written as a fraction of two integers.

Now, we assumed that $x*$ is optimal. Therefore, $c^T x* \ge c^T x, \forall x$ and we have that $Ax* = b$

Now I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm trying to get a contradiction. Maybe I can somehow write $x_i*$ as a fraction of integers, or maybe I can find a rational solution $x-$ that has a higher objective value than $x*$ (i.e. $c^T x- \ge c^T x*$), thus getting a contradiction.

But I'm not sure how to do that.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: do you know revised simplex?

Comment: @LinAlg : I know regular Simplex method. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: The answer also follows from the regular simplex method. The row reduction steps always give a rational $x$ in each iteration.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the optimal solution is a basic feasible solution. Let $x_B$ be the basic variables and $x_N$ be the non-basic solutions.

We know that $x_N=0$, hence it is rational.

We also have $A_Bx_B=b$ where $A_B$ be the matrix corresponding to the basic columns and it is invertible.

We can solve the linear system by [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) where the solutions are quotient of the determinants of integer matrices. We know that determinant of an integer matrices is an integer, and hence their quotient is a rational number.